# My xml files have a invisible character before declation tag <?xml

Tags: xml

My xml files are apparently correct according to the w3c standards. However, to send them to a system (which is not mine) I get an error.
I tried to validate them by http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ site and got this error:

Errors in the XML document:
1: 1 Content is not allowed in prolog.

XML document:
1 Ã ¯ Â »Â ¿

This is the error in my file but there is NO CHARACTER at the beginning of the file.

Please help me!

Comment: Make sure you don't have a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in there.

Comment: Add a snippet of your XML to your question. You can also check by opening your file in a text editor in binary mode. Additionally make sure you are not inadvertently adding a character at the start of the xml when you are reading it in with your code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends by the editor you use it, and the encode to save the xml file.

Try Notepad++ and encode the file with UTF-8 without BOM.

Also, la settings, use Format Windows, or Unix.

Comment: You will probably find that the encoding declaration in your xml header <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> is different to how the file is physically encoded. Use Notepad++ to set the encoding as suggested here.